# CoreData EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) when access empty property

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

When I try to access an empty property after creating an NSManagedObject, it gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

```
let m = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entityName, inManagedObjectContext: context) as MyManagedEntity

println(m.numberProperty) // this is OK
println(m.stringProperty) // this gives me the exception
println(m.dateProperty) // this gives me the exception
```

Any Ideas how to solve it?

EDIT:

I'm also getting `EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode-0x0)` in my Tests when casting to `MyManagedEntity`

Comment: Can you show your property definitions for your entity?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661120/check-if-property-is-set-in-core-data

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify default values for your attributes in your XCDataModel?

If you generate an NSManagedObject subclasses you can change any attribute to an optional by adding a question mark to the declaration:

```
@NSManaged var stringProperty: String?
@NSManaged var dateProperty: NSDate?
```

Elsewhere you can do:

```
println(m.stringProperty?)
if m.stringproperty != nil {
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't declare them as optional actually, I just left as the default generated by Xcode