# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing a String property

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

Crashlytics says about several crashes happened randomly.

Please consider the following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsfeedItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as NewsfeedItemTableViewCell

    let newsfeedItem = self.newsfeedItems[indexPath.row]

    // This line gives crash: EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
    let text = newsfeedItem.text as NSString
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = text

    return cell
}
```

Here is `NewsfeedItem` class:

```
class NewsfeedItem: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
    @NSManaged var sku: String
    @NSManaged var text: String

    var dataItem: DataItem?

}
```

PS: PLEASE NOTE that `NewsfeedItem.text` property IS NOT Optional, so it can't be `nil`!

Comment: Most probably you are accessing nil when accessing text. Trying using optional if syntax, if (let text = newsfeedItem.text) {//Your code}

Comment: self.newsfeedItems..??

Comment: How it's possible? `text` is not `Optional`

Comment: Even for optional Core Data properties, Xcode (unfortunately) generates a non-optional Swift property (so it *can* be nil if the Core Data property has not been set!). See [Check if property is set in Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661120/check-if-property-is-set-in-core-data) for a possible workaround.

Comment: @MartinR, this is much closer to the answer, thanks! Will try that

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your NewsfeedItem text is not nil ? If you are not check it first

```
if let text = newsfeedItem.text as? NSString{
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = text
}
```

Comment: Why should I unwrap non-optional value?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev Check your text attribute in data model inspector if optional check box is checked and default value not set

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea on swift. ***But the exception clearly says that its about the accessing a non String value***. That mean you'r accessing a nil object or different on not an string object .

Probably `self.newsfeedItems` is an object of `NewsfeedItem`, so you'r trying to access a (iVar) string of it.

Comment: `self.newsfeedItems` is an array of `Newsfeed` items. AFAIK in Swift, if I declare a property like this: `var text: String` it can't take a nil value

Comment: `newsfeedItem` make this explicitly an object of `NewsfeedItem`, and then try..
Something like `let newsfeedItem as NewsfeedItem`