# Swift: Check if variable is nil

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I am currently learning Swift and I am experimenting with Core Data where I would like to save a linked list. To add an element at the end of the list I have a while-loop like this:

```
var curr = start
while (curr.nextElem != nil) {
    curr = curr.nextElem
}
```

The problem is though that `curr.next != nil` seems to be invalid, following error is shown: `'ListElem' is not convertible to UInt8`

I noticed this error a few times before but always found a way around comparing but how can this be done in this case?

Comment: I strongly assume that this is a duplicate of [Check if property is set in Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661120/check-if-property-is-set-in-core-data).  – The problem is that even if `nextElem` is defined as optional in the Core Data model inspector, Xcode does not create an optional property in the Swift class. The answer to above question shows a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ListElem.nextElem` property seems to be returning an actual `ListElem`, so it can never be nil. For it to be able to be nil, it has to be of optional type (`ListElem?`).

Also, try the Xcode 6.3 beta — most of the error messages where Swift 1.1 said "I dunno what you're doing, so I'll just say you can't convert it to `UInt8`" have been replaced with better diagnostics in Swift 1.2.

Comment: To download the beta versions you have to be enrolled in a plan which I am not yet (learning comes first)